# Where does Firefox store its cookies on Linux?

Tags: firefox

Where does Firefox store cookies in Linux?
I searched everywhere but did not find anything.

Comment: Yes, of course! File name: `~/.mozilla/firefox/<profile name>/cookies.sqlite`.

Comment: Please only ask one question per question. Also, the part about Windows is off topic; you should try Super User.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Firefox stores cookies in sqlite database `~/.mozilla/firefox/<profile path>/cookies.sqlite`. You can have full access to it.

For example, to watch all cookies from stackoverflow.com you can do:

```
cd  ~/.mozilla/firefox/<profile path>/
sqlite3 cookies.sqlite
select * from moz_cookies where baseDomain glob '*stackoverflow*'
```

(replace here `<profile path>` by path of your firefox profile).

To see names of database fields do: `.schema`.

Comment: Just one thing to add. The [SQLite Manager](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/sqlite-manager/) Firefox extension can open the current profile's databases and display the table data in sortable and searchable grid. Suitable for regular users not familiar with SQL syntax.

Comment: This has changed a number of times over the years; maybe you want to add Firefox version information and/or a link to the [MozillaZine Knowledge Base](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Cookies#Where_are_cookies_stored)

Answer (score 3):

Those answers are outdated in 2020 or at least it didn't work for me on OpenSUSE leap 15.2 Firefox 78.2

I followed the top rated answer with some tweaks found from googling so:

> cd ~/.mozilla/firefox/<random string profile path>/

It seems that Mozilla has locked the database so you'll need to copy it

> cp cookies.sqlite cooking.sqlite

Then you can do

> sqlite3 cooking.sqlite

To list all the different tables if you need to sort by something other then domain

> PRAGMA table_info(moz_cookies);

I get all those tables (note that baseDomain isn't there)

id| originAttributes | name| value| host | path | expiry | lastAccessed | creationTime | isSecure | isHttpOnly | inBrowserElement | sameSite | rawSameSite

> SELECT * FROM moz_cookies WHERE host GLOB '*domain*';
>
> or
>
> SELECT value FROM moz_cookies WHERE host GLOB '*domain*';

---

Although this listed all my stored cookies I was not able to see "temporary" cookies, I confirmed it by running:

> SELECT id FROM moz_cookies;

This gives me a list of 8 ID and if I go to
Preference>security>manage data
it list only 8

This shows how glob works because the answer wasn't really clear on that
https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-glob/

This is where I got the idea of just copying the cookie database, Note that the file needs to end with sqlite
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4706537/firefox-locks-places-sqlite

Answer (score 1):

Since you didn't specify if you were looking for that storage outside or inside of Firefox, another really good way to access and edit cookies comes from the Web Developer | Storage Inspector:

[image]

[image]

[image]

You can add, remove, and edit cookies for a given web site.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a text file with the cookie information, you can dump all your cookies using different add-ons.

When I needed cookies for downloading using wget, I dumped using [Export Cookies](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/export-cookies/) and then loaded them in wget using `wget --load-cookies <cookiefile>`

Answer (score -1):

Others have provided great detail.  I would just like to add to the discussion that you can search through your cookies (and optionally remove them) by going into "Open Menu">Preferences>Privacy>"remove individual cookies" link.

For all intensive purposes, using the sqlite method provided to browse through the cookies database is of course far superior, as it is a database and you can use SQL statements on the data.