# Why I can't find cookies from websites accessed via IP address on Firefox cookies.sqlite?

Tags: firefox

Regarding this [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/82597/where-does-firefox-store-its-cookies-on-linux), I was setting some cookies on a PythonFlask app which is accessed directly via http://127.0.0.1:8000, and I realized that it seems that, after accessing the address above, no such information regarding the SITE was stored in cookies.sqlite.

For example:

**OK**

```
$ sqlite3 cookies.sqlite "select * from moz_cookies where baseDomain glob '*stackoverflow*'"

357167|stackoverflow.com||cc|0d41064c61774c12b5d369694f729429|stackoverflow.com|/|1784567753|1469906956225907|1469034954014292|0|0|0|0
366821|stackoverflow.com||_gat|1|.stackoverflow.com|/|1469907557|1469906957098821|1469906957098821|0|0|0|0
```

**NOK**

```
 $ sqlite3 cookies.sqlite "select * from moz_cookies where baseDomain glob '*127.0.0.1*'"
 $
```

I made a dump of this SQlite database (~/.mozilla/firefox/*.default/cookies.sqlite) and I tried to grep the the IP, but no good.

```
~/.mozilla/firefox/2r7mbtt8.default $ sqlite3 cookies.sqlite .dump > mozilla-30-07-2016.sql
~/.mozilla/firefox/2r7mbtt8.default $ grep --color "127.0.0.1" mozilla-30-07-2016.sql 
~/.mozilla/firefox/2r7mbtt8.default $
```

I was checking directly on Mozilla Firefox (Privacy > remove individual cookies), that the cookie was indeed stored.

[image]

With this, I have the following questions regarding Firefox:

- Does it make some distinction when it comes to store cookies from websites that are accessed via IP address or IP+port ?
- Does it store cookies from sites accessed via IP addresses in another SQlite database?

Comment: There must be a distinction on websites accessed by IP+port because the design of the **same origin policy** includes only unique hostnames based on domain name (And going to IP+port does not send the Host: header).  Yet, I do not know how firefox stores the cookies for non-domian based pages.  Moreover `localhost` is a **very** special security case for browsers.

Comment: I see.. But I'm pretty sure that it does not stores in cookies.sqlite.
I tried to search for the IP on other *sqlite files in "~/.mozilla/firefox/*.default", and there are some informations indeed, but these other databases don't seem to have the same data structure from "cookies.sqlite" database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it works here.

```
sqlite> select * from moz_cookies where basedomain='127.0.0.1';
56447|127.0.0.1||mythweb_id|popn9pcsh52ut89d1g1a601us6|127.0.0.1|/|1501456297|1469920297288887|1469920297288887|0|0|0|0
```

perhaps your cookie is a session cookie, not a persistent cookie. session cookies are not saved.