# Where are firefox cookies in Linux?

Tags: firefox, cookie

I want to find out where are firefox cookies getting stored in Linux. there is a similar old question [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/82597/where-does-firefox-store-its-cookies-on-linux) which says that the cookies are stored at `~.mozilla/firefox/<profile name>/cookies.sqlite`
but i think this is not true anymore because i remove this file but i still have cookies in firefox itself. also i tested the entire `~.mozilla/firefox` folder with `inotifywait` using the following command:

```bash
$ inotifywait -mr .mozilla/firefox -e open -e access -e modify
```

and got nothing!. not even an access event occur when i open firefox and search or open any sites.

Comment: I this on Ubuntu? If so the active profile has moved to `~/snap/firefox/common/.mozilla/firefox/`

Comment: Have you checked the cache file? Firefox cache is kept under ~/.mozilla/firefox/*.default/Cache.

Comment: What happens when you nuke your ~/.cache/mozilla/firefox/<profile> folder?

Comment: **Have you actually exited Firefox?** If you haven't the file is still open and Firefox is using it. `~/.mozilla/firefox/<profile name>/cookies.sqlite` **is** the correct location unless you're using snap/flatpak.

Comment: thank you all. it was snap and the path is `~/snap/firefox/common/.mozilla/firefox` thank you @ams

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to know what path firefox is using for your current profile you can check this with `about:profiles` or `about:support` in the **url bar**.

In recent versions of Firefox, the cookie storage location in Linux has been changed.

The cookies now stored in a format called `cookies.sqlite` within the Firefox profile directory.

`~/.mozilla/firefox/YOURPROFILE/cookies.sqlite`

`YOURPROFILE`, if you are using more then one profile, otherwise it's something with `default`.

If using snap you will find the cookie file in `~/snap/firefox/common/.mozilla`.

*Check this too, for experimental technology:*

> There are other storage mechanisms for cookies in recent versions, such as **IndexedDB** and the **HTTP cookies storage API**.
> Check the Browser compatibility table carefully before using this in production.

[Cookie Store API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Cookie_Store_API)

[Using HTTP cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies?retiredLocale=de)

[IndexedDB API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API?retiredLocale=de)

[Using IndexedDB](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API/Using_IndexedDB?retiredLocale=de)